# Can you implement a generic struct for multiple types?

Tags: rust

I have a generic struct `Dit<T>` that implements the FFT for T:

```
struct Dit<T> {
    n: usize,
    exponents: Bin<f32, Complex<T>>,
    tmp: Option<Vec<Complex<T>>>,
}

impl Dit<f32> {
    /// Create a new instance
    ///
    /// Notice that the number of samples that will be processed by an instance
    /// is always fixed, because the exponent values are precalculated.
    ///
    /// # Parameters
    /// - `n` The number of samples this operator can process, eg. 1024
    pub fn new(n: usize) -> Result<Dit<f32>, FFTError> {
        if 2.pow((n as f64).log2() as usize) != n {
            return Err(FFTError::InvalidLength);
        }

        let rtn = Dit {
            n: n,
            exponents: Bin::new(),
            tmp: None,
        }.pregen();

        return Ok(rtn);
    }

    // ...
}
```

I started to add the implementation for `f64`:

```
impl Dit<f64> {
    pub fn new(n: usize) -> Result<Dit<f64>, FFTError> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
    // ...
}
```

...and I'm getting these sorts of errors:

```
src/impls/dit.rs:186:7: 196:4 error: duplicate definition of value `new`
src/impls/dit.rs:186   pub fn new(n:usize) -> Result<Dit<f64>, FFTError> {
src/impls/dit.rs:187     if 2.pow((n as f64).log2() as usize) != n {
src/impls/dit.rs:188       return Err(FFTError::InvalidLength);
src/impls/dit.rs:189     }
src/impls/dit.rs:190     let rtn = Dit {
src/impls/dit.rs:191       n: n,
                     ...
src/impls/dit.rs:110:7: 120:4 note: first definition of value `new` here
src/impls/dit.rs:110   pub fn new(n:usize) -> Result<Dit<f32>, FFTError> {
src/impls/dit.rs:111     if 2.pow((n as f64).log2() as usize) != n {
src/impls/dit.rs:112       return Err(FFTError::InvalidLength);
src/impls/dit.rs:113     }
src/impls/dit.rs:114     let rtn = Dit {
src/impls/dit.rs:115       n: n,
```

I am confused. My impression was that for the generic `Foo<T>`, the implementation `Foo<Bar1>` is a different concrete instance to the implementation of `Foo<Bar2>`. As such, I was under the impression that I could have different instances of methods for each concrete instance.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Many `impl`s are allowed, but only one definition of any given method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to solve your task with such syntax (at least, I cannot find any examples in the rust reference book).

But there are some working constructions like:

```
impl<T> Dit<T> where T: Float {
```

or:

```
trait DitTrait {
    fn new(n: usize) -> Result<Self, FFTError>;
}

impl DitTrait for Dit<f32> { ... }
impl DitTrait for Dit<f64> { ... }
```